# How to load a SKTileSet in Xcode 8 and AppleTV Simulator in code?

Tags: sprite-kit, load, ios-simulator, tvos

I'm trying to load a tile set which I've defined using the Xcode 8 Beta 2  tile set editor.

But when I try to load the SKTileSet using this line of code:

```
   tileSet = SKTileSet(named: "tilesetName")
```

I get the following messages in the console of Xcode for about 20 times:

```
SKUtil.m: MGGetBoolAnswer is not available in the simulator.
```

Regardless of what name I provide as the tile set name - I always get this message in the console and the **tileSet** - Variable is **nil**.

Any ideas?

Was someone able to load a tile set programmatically in the Simulator so far?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Frank

Answer (score 1):

This is a harmless message. It will be removed in the next release. Sorry for the confusion.

[More info](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62983)